# Not too sure how a URI works regarding absolute paths to files

Tags: java, windows, io

Simple question: why am I getting `new IllegalArgumentException: Path component should be '/'` when trying to create a zip filesystem at the following URI:

**file:E:/somedirectory/somefile**

But this seems to work: **file:/somedirectory/somefile**

What if I have the same paths on two different drives and I need to access a specific one? Or am I completely missing the point of URIs in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For paths that use windows volumes use the following format:

```
file:///e:/somedirectory/somefile
```

The triple `///` results from omitting the URL *hostname* for local files. Compare: `file://sometherhost/e:/somedirectory/somefile`, which is valid according to the URI spec, if not actually useful for accessing files on remote volumes.

Comment: It should be noted that `file://` URIs with a hostname are valid according to the spec, but there's no specified way to access them, so they are pretty much used for informative uses, not for actually *accessing* those (remote) files.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Backslashes are used to point directories and files

**2.** Try it this way...

```
         `E:\\somedirectory\\somefile`
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its easier to do it with the URI builder. I always use it:

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
builder.setSchema("file").setHost("anyhost").setPath("/yourpath/");
URI uri;
uri = builder.build();
```

you can check your URI:

```
System.out.println(uri.toString());
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Where is this class from? I can't seen to find it anywhere.

Comment: URIBuilder is part of .NET. This question is about java

Comment: I used the code above in a java project ;-) this is the package I had to import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder. I have no idea, where I downloaded it, sorry. But it´s certainly java code